# Writing if-statements more concisely

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript (and most other programming languages), I've noticed that it's difficult to write if-statments concisely when checking multiple coniditions for the same variable, and performing the same action for each condition. Is it possible to write if-statements more concisely in scenarios like this?

```
if(x==1|x==2|x==3){ //Is there any way to make this less verbose?
    console.log("X equals either 1 or 2 or 3!");
}

//this isn't syntactically correct, but it's more concise,
//and I wish it were possible to write it more like this
if(x==(1|2|3)){
    console.log("X equals either 1 or 2 or 3!");
}
```

Comment: It seems like your question is used as a mental challenge to provide all kinds of elaborate answers. But I suspect the real answer is "no".

Comment: @simon No, I actually want to find a way to write if-statements less verbosely (so that I won't need to write a lot of redundant code.) Using regular expressions (as shown in the answer below) would be one solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
if (/^(1|2|3)$/.test(x)) { ... }
```

Comment: That's hardly "more concise" in the sense of "marked by brevity of expression or statement : free from all elaboration and superfluous detail" (nor by the amount of characters used).

Comment: @vaugham Have you found any cases where it doesn't work with 2 digits? It appears to be working in this example, where one of the numbers has 2 digits: http://jsfiddle.net/JH6PQ/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
if ([1, 2, 3].indexOf(x) >= 0) { ... }
```

If you need a more complex test of equality, you can define your own function and use it with the built-in `some()` iterator:

```
function match(value1, value2) { var result = . . .; return result; }

if ([1, 2, 3].some(match.bind(null, x))) { . . . }
```

(`bind` appeared in JS 1.8.5; if you need backward compatibility, you can use:

```
if ([1, 2, 3].some(function(elt) {return match(x, elt);})) { . . . }
```

Answer (score 1):

or

```
if([1, 2, 3].indexOf(x) !== -1){} //since JS 1.6
```

[Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, most of the time you can make if statements much more concise just by defining a method which returns a bool. You make the code much more readable, it's easier to test and maybe you are even reusing more code this way.

Of course the other answers are handy too.

One example as requested:

```
if (password.length < 6 || ! /[0-9]/.test(password) || password == userName) {
    alert('password doesn\'t meet security standards!');
}
```

vs.

```
function isSecurePassword(pw, userName) {
    if (password.length < 6) return false;
    if (/[0-9]/.test(password)) return false;
    if (password == userName) return false;

    return true;
}

if ( ! isSecurePassword(pw, userName)) {
    alert(..);
}
```

(normally you likely would have objects and methods and wouldn't have to pass around variables)

Comment: Do you have any examples of such a method? I'm interested in seeing the solutions you've found.

Comment: @AndersonGreen i have added an example :) was it something like that you wanted to see or are you interested in something more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I've often wondering about a short hand for multiple if statements using the same value.

If you got some free time, I would recommend exploring some of JS's functional programming constructs.  You might be able to achieve a more elegant solution.

I couldn't come up with a good or statement off the top of my head, but 'AND' seem like a no brainier.

```
var Cond = {
    'and': function(val, predicates) {
        return predicates.every( function(predicate) { return predicate(val) } );
    }
}

var predicates = [
    function(val) { return val > 40; }
    function(val) { return val < 45; }
    function(val) { return val === 42; }
];

console.log( Cond.and( 42, predicates ) );
```

My example is super lame but you should be easy enough to play around with.